# Getting 401 Unauthorized when activating Keycloak policy-enforcer

Tags: spring, scope, authorization, keycloak, policy

I'm trying to integrate with Keycloak Authorization Services (resource, scopes, policies, permissions). I'm using version 16.1.0.

For starters I have created a realm and a client. For the client I have enabled Direct Access Grants (to allow generating tokens directly from curl), Access Type is set to confidentails and also enabled Authorization.

[image]

The Authorization setup is as follows:

- I have a Products Resource to which the scopes get, post, put and delete are configured
- I have Policies associating specific roles to them (customer can get, service rep can get, post and put and admin can get, post, put and delete)
- Created Permissions for each of the roles/policies, ie, Customer permission has get scope and Customer policy associated. Service Rep has post/put scopes and Service Rep Policy and Admin permission has get/post/put/delete scopes and Admin Policy

I have evaluated these configs on Keycloak and they all work fine.

I then created a Spring Boot app with Spring Security and created a Products REST controller to test. Here is my config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class KeycloakConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource(){
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Content-Type"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

The ProductController:

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {
    public ProductController() {
    }

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public ResponseEntity getAll(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Returning all products");
    }

    @GetMapping("/product/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity getById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Returning product with id " + id);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/product")
    public ResponseEntity create(){
        return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/product"))
                .body("item created successfully");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/product", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity update(){
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/product/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity delete(@PathVariable String id){
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

The application.properties is set as follows:

```
keycloak.realm=my-realm
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.credentials.secret=my-secret
keycloak.resource=my-client
keycloak.public-client=false

keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.enforcement-mode=ENFORCING
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].name=Products Resource
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].path=/products
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].methods[0].method=GET
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].methods[0].scopes=get
```

I then use curl to generate an access token:

```
curl -v -L -X POST 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=my-client' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=my-secret' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid' \
--data-urlencode 'username=my-username' \
--data-urlencode 'password=my-password'
```

I get the access token successfully. I use this access token to fetch the Products controller:

```
curl -v -L 'http://localhost:8082/products' -H 'Authorization: Bearer {access_token}'
```

I get the following response:

```
{"timestamp":"2022-01-18T10:17:38.223+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","path":"/products"}
```

I even tried getting an RPT token which permissions already included by doing the following curl:

```
curl -X POST \
http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/OnePortalFramework/protocol/openid-connect/token \
-H "Authorization: Bearer {access_token}" \
--data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket" \
--data "audience=opf-sb-ms1"
```

And using this token I get the exact some error.

I debugged the app and it fails when the keycloak adapter tries to get the permissions from the server (PolicyEnforcer.java, line 174 `resource = protectedResource.findByName(resourceName);`). Apparently it does not have a token (it doesn't use the token I passed when making the ProductsController request) and just fails.

Stacktrace if it helps:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to obtain policy enforcer
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getPolicyEnforcer(KeycloakDeployment.java:553) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.AuthenticatedActionsHandler.corsRequest(AuthenticatedActionsHandler.java:108) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.AuthenticatedActionsHandler.handledRequest(AuthenticatedActionsHandler.java:54) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:69) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:92) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:214) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:232) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:96) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:403) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:144) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find resource
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.Throwables.retryAndWrapExceptionIfNecessary(Throwables.java:91) ~[keycloak-authz-client-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.find(ProtectedResource.java:232) ~[keycloak-authz-client-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.findByName(ProtectedResource.java:131) ~[keycloak-authz-client-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.PolicyEnforcer.configureDefinedPaths(PolicyEnforcer.java:174) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.PolicyEnforcer.configurePaths(PolicyEnforcer.java:160) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.PolicyEnforcer.<init>(PolicyEnforcer.java:76) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder$1.call(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:154) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder$1.call(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:147) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getPolicyEnforcer(KeycloakDeployment.java:551) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponseException: Unexpected response from server: 401 / Unauthorized
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethod.execute(HttpMethod.java:95) ~[keycloak-authz-client-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethodResponse$2.execute(HttpMethodResponse.java:50) ~[keycloak-authz-client-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.TokenCallable.clientCredentialsGrant(TokenCallable.java:123) ~[keycloak-authz-client-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.TokenCallable.obtainTokens(TokenCallable.java:154) ~[keycloak-authz-client-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.TokenCallable.call(TokenCallable.java:64) ~[keycloak-authz-client-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.createFindRequest(ProtectedResource.java:296) ~[keycloak-authz-client-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.access$300(ProtectedResource.java:38) ~[keycloak-authz-client-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource$5.call(ProtectedResource.java:225) ~[keycloak-authz-client-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource$5.call(ProtectedResource.java:222) ~[keycloak-authz-client-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.find(ProtectedResource.java:230) ~[keycloak-authz-client-16.1.0.jar:16.1.0]
```

Does anyone have ideas to what this could be?